# WebView at the return of activityForResult button doesn't Work

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-webview

I have MainActivity that contains webview, that inside I load a html file that I have in assets folder.
This HTML looks like this: (is very simple for the moment)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
              <h2>capture=camera</h2>  
              <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

when the button inside the html is clicked, then a CameraActivity is launched, that returns Uri of the Image taked.

And here come's the problem. Because in MainActivity, at the return, the webview loads ok, but, the button inside don't respond any more.

MainAcitivy:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setWebView();
        startWebView();

        Log.d("CAMERA", "UNO");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        setWebView();
        startWebView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        setWebView();
        startWebView();
    }

    private void setWebView() {
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webview.loadUrl(URL);
    }
    private void startWebView() {

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(URL);
                return true;

            }
        });


        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,String acceptType) {

                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,CAM_ACT);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:" + e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            // openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {

                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

        }); // End setWebChromeClient



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAM_ACT) {
            Log.d("Camera", "Activity result -->" + data.getExtras().getString("result"));
        }
        webview = null;
        setWebView();
        startWebView();
    }
```

The Log returns this message when I click the button again:

```
02-14 11:01:40.048: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(16553): blockWebkitDraw
02-14 11:01:40.048: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(16553): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks for all.

---

**EDIT for solution**

The solution for my problem was solved in this way (provided by @ksasq)
in "OnActivityResult" I had to add the lines of mUploadMessage to solve it

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // webview.loadUrl(URL);
        if (requestCode == CAM_ACT) {
            Log.d("Camera", "Activity result -->" + data.getExtras().getString("result"));
            Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : data.getData();
            this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            this.mUploadMessage = null;
        }


        setWebView();
        startWebView();
    }
```

Comment: why are you setting webview to null in onActivityForResult?

Comment: @ksasq was a try to make it work again. I set to null because in setWebView() I attach it again. But doesn't works

Comment: OK, I reread your code and I think I spotted the problem. Please see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive the file back in `onActivityResult` you need to send the uploadMessage that was passed into `openFileChooser` back to WebKit. Something like:

```
uploadMsg.receiveValue(data.getExtras().getString("result"))
```

Please note that the file chooser methods are @hidden and not part of the public Android SDK. They may not be supported in the future. Indeed, they are not working in Android 4.4 and there are no workarounds for this.

Comment: It Worked perfect. I'll edit my question with the solution adapted to my problem.

Thanks for all.